# i want to know, how to display values from controller to view page. the values are fetched from database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i fetch some values from database using laravel 5. but i have no idea to display that values to the view page please help me.

this is my controller code for fetch values from database

```php
public function getcategory()
{
    $category =DB::select('select CategoryTitle from category');
    echo json_encode($category);
}
```

this is my route

```php
Route::get('/addworkout/category',array('uses'=>'WorkoutController@getcategory'));
```

Comment: Have you tried using [Blade templates](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#displaying-data)?

Comment: Please read more about the framework before posting the question, this is one of the basic features of the framework, and as mentioned by @Alphonsus, it's called Blade.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple get data from database and show in views

1. Fetch data and return to view

   ```
   public function getCategory()
   {
        //Get category from db
        $category =DB::select('select CategoryTitle from category');

        //It will return your category as data to post view 
        return view('pages.post')->withData($category)
   }
   ```
2. Display category name in view

   ```
   @foreach ($data as $cate)
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item">{{ $cate->name }}</a>
   @endforeach
   ```